# enabling proposed repos in 15.04 server fails to update packages

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, 15.04

i am trying to use the proposed repo of vivid on ubuntu 15.04 server system.

```
user@controller:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=15.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=vivid
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 15.04"
```

i added the below line to /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-proposed multiverse main restricted universe
```

when i try to use aptitude -t vivid-proposed i am greeted with below error:

```
E: The value 'vivid-proposed' is invalid for APT:: Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources.
```

i am following the steps detailed at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed

am i missing something?